# TIMEDIFF com exceção de período (Horário comercial)

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, tenho uma consulta SQL que me retorna a diferença de horas entre 2 datas, porém eu precisaria calcular esta diferença adicionando um período (08:00 - 18:00)
por exemplo:

Data inicial: 2019-10-18 **15:00:00**

Data Final: 2019-10-19 **09:00:00**

Resultado esperado: **04:00:00**

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(tb_paradas.data_fechamento,tb_paradas.data_abertura) AS difSla FROM tb_paradas
```

Como posso adicionar a exceção de horário comercial na minha consulta? Seria mais fácil eu tratar isto via consulta sql ou no php?

Comment: Adicionando ou considerando apenas o horário comercial que, por sinal, pode variar.

Comment: considerando somente o horário 08:00 - 18:00

Comment: Considerando que o intervalo possa ser de vários dias então você precisa considerar a hora inicial e a final dia a dia e ir acumulando. Além disso precisa também desconsiderar fins de semana e feriados.

Comment: pela complexidade eu não cogitei em incluir feriados e finais de semana por enquanto.. e sim tratar isso no php para o usuário não conseguir cadastrar registros nestes peíodos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido via php..
Caso alguém com o mesmo problema segue me código ja considerando sábado/domingo e array para feriado..
Detalhe no código que para sábado o período é diferente que também foi adaptado no código (horário das 07:30 - 11:00)

```
function convertHoras($horasInteiras) {

    // Define o formato de saida
    $formato = '%02d:%02d';
    // Converte para minutos
    $minutos = $horasInteiras * 60;
    // Converte para o formato hora
    $horas = floor($minutos / 60);
    $minutos = ($minutos % 60);
    // Retorna o valor
    return sprintf($formato, $horas, $minutos);
}                 

function isFeriado($dia){

    $arrayFeriados = [
        "2018-08-10"
    ];

    if(in_array($dia,$arrayFeriados)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function getHoras($dataIni,$dataFim,$pausa){

 $datatime1 = new DateTime($dataIni);
 $datatime2 = new DateTime($dataFim);
 $intervaloEmMinuto = new DateInterval('PT1M');
 $periodo = new DatePeriod($datatime1, $intervaloEmMinuto, $datatime2);
 $minutos = 0;


foreach ($periodo as $data) {

    $dia = $data->format("Y-m-d");  

   if(substr($data->format("D"), 0, 2) == 'Su' || isFeriado($dia)){

    continue;

  }

   /* @var $data \DateTime */

   $dataEmMinuto = clone $data;

    // Horário de entrada - Seg/Sabado
   $inicioDoPrimeiroTurno = clone $dataEmMinuto->setTime(7, 29, 0);

   // Horário de saída
   if(substr($data->format("D"), 0, 2) == 'Sa') { 
   // Se sábado = 11:00
    $fimDoPrimeiroTurno = clone $dataEmMinuto->setTime(11, 00, 0);
   } else {
   // Dias da semana = 17:00
    $fimDoPrimeiroTurno = clone $dataEmMinuto->setTime(17, 00, 0);   
   }

   if (($inicioDoPrimeiroTurno < $data && $data < $fimDoPrimeiroTurno)) {

     $minutos++;

   }
}

 $intervalo = new DateInterval("PT{$minutos}M");
 $data = new DateTime();
 $dataAtual = clone $data;
 $data->add($intervalo);
 $data->sub(new DateInterval("PT".abs($pausa)."M"));
 $d = $dataAtual->diff($data);
 $seconds = $d->s + ($d->i * 60) + ($d->h * 3600) + ($d->d * 86400) + ($d->m * 2592000); // and so on

$hour= $seconds/3600;

return $hour;

}

// $data_abertura e $data_fechamento = são os valores que vem pelo banco de dados
echo $slaFinal = convertHoras(getHoras($data_abertura,$data_fechamento,false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido via php.. Caso alguém com o mesmo problema segue me código ja considerando sábado/domingo e array para feriado.. Detalhe no código que para sábado o período é diferente que também foi adaptado no código (horário das 07:30 - 11:00)

Usei sua solução e deu super certo, só que tive uma situação que precisei calcular diferença entre datas, dai tirei o calculo de horas e deixei só dias, até ai tudo bem. Só que para o meu caso, é para calcular dias de atestado, no caso teria que contar o dia inicial, ex; de 15/03/2022 a 16/03/2022, atualmente daria 1 dia de diferença entre as datas, teria como fazer com que esses primeiro dia contasse ?
Pensei em colocar +1 no final da conta, porem quando faço isso, se alguém colocar uma data que começa na sexta até domingo, deveria conta apenas a sexta, mas se coloco +1 ai fica 2 dias que é o errado. Teria como me ajudar com essa situação ?

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Se tiver uma nova pergunta, faça-a clicando no botão [Fazer pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Inclua um link para esta pergunta se ajudar a fornecer contexto. - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/376348)